# How to pass current() to template in hautelook fixtures

Tags: symfony, fixtures, faker, nelmio-alice

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and this bundle https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle

This is my YAML file

```
AppBundle\Entity\Product:
  template_product (template):
    unit:              !php/const AppBundle\Entity\ItemInterface::UNIT_PCS

  product_teeth_{1} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng sứ kim loại Mỹ ( BH 3 năm )
    price:             1500000
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_<current()>_1", "@category_product_<current()>_2"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_<current()>_1", "@store_product_<current()>_2"]

  product_teeth_{2} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng sứ Vita Đức ( BH 4 năm )
    price:             1800000
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_<current()>_1", "@category_product_<current()>_2"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_<current()>_1", "@store_product_<current()>_2"]

  product_teeth_{3} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng toàn sứ Zirconia ( CAD/CAM ) ( BH 7 năm )
    price:             3900000
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_<current()>_1", "@category_product_<current()>_2"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_<current()>_1", "@store_product_<current()>_2"]

  product_teeth_{4} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng sứ Titan ( BH 5 năm )
    price:             2400000
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_<current()>_1", "@category_product_<current()>_2"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_<current()>_1", "@store_product_<current()>_2"]

  product_teeth_{5} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng toàn sứ Full Zirconia ( CAD/CAM ) ( BH 10 năm )
    price:             4400000
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_<current()>_1", "@category_product_<current()>_2"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_<current()>_1", "@store_product_<current()>_2"]

  product_teeth_{6} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng toàn sứ Lava Plus - Ceramay (BH 20 năm)
    price:             1200000
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_<current()>_1", "@category_product_<current()>_2"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_<current()>_1", "@store_product_<current()>_2"]

AppBundle\Entity\CategoryProduct:
  template_category_product (template):
    id:       <(substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 18))>

  template_category_1 (template, extends template_category_product):
    category: "@category_product"
  template_category_2 (template, extends template_category_product):
    category: "@category_product_1"

  category_product_{1..3}_1 (extends template_category_1):
    item:     "@product_teeth_<current()>"
  category_product_{1..3}_2 (extends template_category_2):
    item:     "@product_teeth_<current()>"

AppBundle\Entity\StoreProduct:
  template_store_product (template):
    id:       <(substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 18))>

  template_store_1 (template, extends template_store_product):
    store:    "@store_dentist_1"
  template_store_2 (template, extends template_store_product):
    store:    "@store_dentist_2"

  store_product_{1..3}_1 (extends template_store_1):
    item:     "@product_teeth_<current()>"
  store_product_{1..3}_2 (extends template_store_2):
    item:     "@product_teeth_<current()>"
```

The issue is, as you see these lines. They repeat multiple times:

```
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_<current()>_1", "@category_product_<current()>_2"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_<current()>_1", "@store_product_<current()>_2"]
```

I don't know how to pass the `<current()>` to the template to reduce lines.

Can anybody let me know how to do it?

Is there any way to solve my issue?

I'm not stuck but try to do best practice DRY in YAML when using fixtures library

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer after trying some solutions.

The `current()` should be put at the end

For example the category should be like that:

```
AppBundle\Entity\CategoryProduct:
  template_category_product (template):
    id:       <(substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 18))>

  category_product_1_{1..12} (extends template_category_product):
    category: "@category_product"
    item:     "@product_teeth_<current()>"
  category_product_2_{1..6} (extends template_category_product):
    category: "@category_product_1"
    item:     "@product_teeth_<current()>"
  category_product_2_{7..12} (extends template_category_product):
    category: "@category_product_2"
    item:     "@product_teeth_<current()>"
```

and the product

```
AppBundle\Entity\Product:
  template_product (template):
    unit:              !php/const AppBundle\Entity\ItemInterface::UNIT_PCS
    categoryProducts : ["@category_product_1_<current()>", "@category_product_2_<current()>"]
    storeItems:        ["@store_product_1_<current()>", "@store_product_2_<current()>"]

  product_teeth_{1} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng sứ kim loại Mỹ ( BH 3 năm )
    price:             1500000

  product_teeth_{2} (extends template_product):
    name:              Răng sứ Vita Đức ( BH 4 năm )
    price:             1800000
  ...
```